# Spring Cloud Gateway - writeWith never called in Gateway Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I've got a filter:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.slf4j.MDC;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.rewrite.RewriteFunction;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponseDecorator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class StoreResponseFilter implements GatewayFilter{


    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
                 val response = exchange.getResponse();
        DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();
        ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
                // this is never called
                return super.writeWith(body);
            }

            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeAndFlushWith(Publisher<? extends Publisher<? extends DataBuffer>> body) {
                // this is never called
                return super.writeAndFlushWith(body);
            }
        };

        ServerWebExchange swe = exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build();
        return chain.filter(swe);

    }
}
```

I use Java DSL

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
builder.routes()
.route(id, r->
// ...
r.filters(storeResponseFilter)
//....
}
```

to configure my filter.

I tried those solutions:

[Spring cloud gateway ServerHttpResponseDecorator writeWith not called on receiving response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76078243/spring-cloud-gateway-serverhttpresponsedecorator-writewith-not-called-on-receivi)
(the provided solution uses WebFilter and I use GatewayFilter)

[Spring Cloud Gateway: Modified Response Body is Truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470030/spring-cloud-gateway-modified-response-body-is-truncated)

[How do you read response body in Spring Cloud Gateway (Webflux) POST filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59286520/how-do-you-read-response-body-in-spring-cloud-gateway-webflux-post-filter)

[How to get Original response body in Spring cloud gateway (Webflux) Post filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71465870/how-to-get-original-response-body-in-spring-cloud-gateway-webflux-post-filter)

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1771

But none of them work, when using Java DSL as configuration

I cannot use `modifyResponseBody` with `RewriteFunction<String, String>`, because I don't store responses from some endpoints because responses are too big and consume too much memory. Unfortunately RewriteFunction<String, String> serializes each response to a String even if I don't do anything with it.

I've read that I need to set a filter order to `NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER - 1` to be before Netty, but I cannot use it when routes are defined with a  RouteLocator customRouteLocator.

**My question is**

How to access (no need to modify) response body in Spring Gateway without serializing ALL responses to Strings, only some of them?

Assume that the logic to determine which request should be handled is non-trivial and several filters which set custom attributes in `exchange` need to be executed to determine that.

I'd like to use Java DSL as it gives the most flexibility.

I use spring-cloud-starter-gateway v 3.1.3. I am not able to change version at the moment.